# Why is IE9 only showing a black page?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer

I have Win 7 Home, when I upgraded IE from version 8 to 9 , It not display any content but a black page, what's the problem? finally I downgraded it to the previous version.

Comment: Have you upgraded IE through Windows Update or from the official installer file?

Comment: I upgraded it using Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an error with Flash. Uninstall Adobe Flash and see if that corrects the error. Then try the newest version **after** you've verified this to be the cause.